# Protecting MS excel JavaScript API add-in

Tags: javascript, excel, api

sorry in advance if this is a silly question - is there anyway to protect published excel add-in JavaScript code from competitors? I have read about obfuscation though wonder if this will be permitted by the MS Partner review process.
I am putting a lot of effort into developing and publishing an excel JavaScript API, and I hope that the code is inherently protected but cannot find any literature on this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An Office Add-in includes two basic components: an XML manifest file, and your own web application. The manifest defines various settings, including how your add-in integrates with Office clients. Your web application needs to be hosted on a web server, or web hosting service, such as Microsoft Azure.

The manifest is an XML file that specifies settings and capabilities of the add-in includes:

- The add-in's display name, description, ID, version, and default
  locale.
- How the add-in integrates with Office.
- The permission level and data access requirements for the add-in.

so when your customer download the add-in, they actually download the manifest file, they still need to access the your web application hosted in web server.

[image]